# What does "The DBMS returned an unspecified error. The command code was 193." mean?

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion

Anyone have an idea of what this means for MS SQL Server?  I'm also calling this from ColdFusion, although I'm guessing that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Google implies that error 193 is a problem with the service.  Does this happen for every query, or just one?  Can you connect from SQL Management Studio?

Comment: It was a one off thing, so it's possible that there was just a hickup in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom JDBC driver?  Try the one that comes with CF.